# What is the best way to count like-values in JS for a Histogram?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, for-loop

I am trying to create histograms of randomly generated data, so currently I am doing the following:

Let's say the following array is created:

```
returns = [0.0024, 0.0231, 0.014, 0.0005, -0.008]
```

I go through the array using:

```
 returnsRounded[x] = Math.round(returns[x] * 1000) / 1000;
```

And this will return me:

```
returnsRounded = [0.002, 0.023, 0.014, 0.001, -0.008]
```

Now I am trying to count the number of each particular value (in an array of tens of thousands of values, so I very inefficiently will do something akin to:

```
switch (returnsRounded) {
    case -0.040:
        arr[1]++;
        break;
    case -0.038:
        arr[2]++;
        break;
    // ... and so on.
}
```

And then plug the counted values into my histogram (which works like a bar chart -- in the sense that it only compares counts. I can't just plug in an array and get a histogram.

So is there any more efficient way of counting the number of occurrences of a rounded number in an array that is faster or more pretty than what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Edit: I came up with a much better than my current way, though I don't know if it is still great. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/brockwhittaker/bLu4s8sc/

Comment: Just use an object with keys instead of dozens of variables and cases?!

Comment: Please show how to plug the counted values into your histogram. If the API is reasonable, it should give you a hint on how to do it.

Comment: I'm using a custom canvas. I can plug the frequency of values as such:
[1,2,3,6,9,15,18,19,20,19,16,12,10,8,5,4,3,2,2,2,1,1]

Comment: Then what do you mean by "*I can't just plug in an array*"? That seems to *be* an array of frequencies.

Comment: I need to get the frequencies though.. That's what this question is about -- how to get the frequency of a number.

Comment: Well, counting them is totally fine. Only you will not want to use a `switch` statement.

Comment: What is preferable to a switch statement?

Comment: Use some maths to get from `-0.04` to `1`, from `-0.038` to `2`, from `-0.036` to `3` etc. You'll notice the pattern.

Comment: your jsfiddle unfortunately doesn't seem to load, jsfiddle gets stuck

Answer (score 2):

They key to counting frequencies is to bin the elements of your array:

```
function frequencies(values, binsize) {
    var mapped = values.map(function(val) { 
       return Math.ceil(val / binsize) -1; 
    });
    return mapped.reduce(function (freqs, val, i) {
      var bin = (binsize * val);
      freqs[bin] = freqs[bin] ? freqs[bin] + 1 : 1;
      return freqs;
    }, {});
}
```

The function `frequencies` creates a dictionary (object) where each key/value pair is the bin/count, e.g.:

```
Object { 0: 60, 1: 43, 2: 11, -0.2: 68, -2: 11, -2.2: 10, -2.4000000000000004: 4, -2.6: 5, -2.8000000000000003: 1, -3: 1, 18 more… }
```

A full sample with a simple histogram is available in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg3Lh5x2/10/)

Comment: You need to increase your integer by 1. This function shows the numbers incorrectly.

Comment: @Cybernetic Thanks, I could not find an issue,as the integer is increased by freqs[bin]++. However, I changed the freqs update to be an explicit assignment for clarity.