# How to include zero counts in a javascript frequency counting function for histograms

Tags: javascript, frequency-distribution

Need some help please - am using the excellent response to this [histogram bucketing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394409/what-is-the-best-way-to-count-like-values-in-js-for-a-histogram) as per code below. My question is what is the most elegant way to get my buckets with zero counts represented in the function output?

Current Output is:

```
[ [ '0', 2 ],
  [ '32', 1 ],
  [ '64', 2 ],
  [ '80', 1 ],
  [ '96', 1 ],
  [ '112', 1 ] ]
```

which omits to note buckets 16 and 48 which have zero counts.

My desired output is:

```
[ [ '0', 2 ],
  [ '16', 0 ],
  [ '32', 1 ],
  [ '48', 0 ],
  [ '64', 2 ],
  [ '80', 1 ],
  [ '96', 1 ],
  [ '112', 1 ] ]
```

All help much appreciated.

```
    function defArrs (){
    
    var arr = [1,16,38,65,78,94,105,124]
    var binsize = 16;
    var check = Object.entries(frequencies (arr,binsize));
    console.log(check);
    }
    
    function frequencies(values, binsize) {
        var mapped = values.map(function(val) { 
           return Math.ceil(val / binsize) -1; 
        });
        console.log(mapped);
        return mapped.reduce(function (freqs, val, i) {
          var bin = (binsize * val);
          freqs[bin] ? freqs[bin]++ : freqs[bin] = 1;
          return freqs;
        }, {});
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting with the empty object for `.reduce`:

```
}, {});
// ^^
```

construct one with all the properties you'll want to be included at the end (starting with a count of 0, of course).

```
const initialObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(
    { length: 7 },
    (_, i) => [i * binsize, 0]
  )
);
```

And pass that as the second parameter to `.reduce`.

That approach also means that this

```
freqs[bin] ? freqs[bin]++ : freqs[bin] = 1;
```

will simplify to

```
freqs[bin]++;
```

Or, [even better](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg):

```
const frequencies = (nums, binsize) => {
  const mapped = nums.map(num => Math.ceil(num / binsize) - 1;
  const grouped = Object.fromEntries(
    { length: 7 },
    (_, i) => [i * binsize, 0]
  );
  for (const val of mapped) {
    grouped[binsize * val]++;
  }
  return grouped;
};
```